# Harmonic waves: direction left or right?

Tags: waves

Consider $E(x,t)=A\sin(kx-\omega t)$ where $k=2\pi / \lambda$, with $\lambda$ the wave length and $A$ its amplitude. We have
$$E(x,t)=A\sin(k(x-vt))$$
so this wave is going to the right. Now, if I want to make it going to the left, I just have to change the sign of $v$ which leads :
$$E(x,t)=A\sin(k(x+vt)).$$
Is that right?
But, in my course it is written that changing the sign of $k$ can change the direction (left or right) of the propagation of the wave, but I don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: What happens if you change the sign of $k$ in $kx - \omega t$?, keeping the sign of $\omega$ fixed? The same thing as what happens when you change the sign of $v$ in $k(x-vt)$. Basically, changing the sign of $\omega / k = v$ changes a left moving to a right moving wave.

Comment: Do you have a program at hand, which allows you to plot these functions? If yes, please start at $t=0$ and increase the time in "small" steps. Use the two functions and see how the wave travels to the left or to the right. If you don't have such a program use [Mathematica online](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bsin%281*%28x+-+1*0.2+%29%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C12%7D%5D), e.g. type "Plot[sin(1*(x - 1*0.2 )), {x, 0, 2*pi}]" and increase the time $t=0.2$.

Comment: Related - [Why is the Plane progressive wave equation $y= a\sin (kx-wt)$ for positive direction of x-axis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251795/104696)

Answer (score 0):

The Plane progressive harminic wave of the form
$$E(x,t)=A\sin(kx-\omega t)$$
where $\omega =kv$ , represents the wave with speed $v$ travelling in $+x$ direction. While $$E(x,t)=A\sin(kx+\omega t)$$
represent the wave with speed $v$ travelling in $-x$ direction. Now Let I change the sign of $k$ form first equation.
$$E(x,t)=A\sin(-kx-\omega t)=-A\sin(kx+\omega t)$$
that is wave moving in $-x$ direction. Similearly changing sign in second equation
$$E(x,t)=A\sin(-kx+\omega t)=-A\sin(kx-\omega t)$$
that is wave moving in $+x$ direction. So Either of these two can be done both are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of the conventions that you choose. A simple choice for a wave travelling in the $±x$ direction is to regard $k$, $v$ [and $\omega$] as positive constants, in which case the direction of travel is determined by whether it is a – or + that appears in the argument of the sine, $(k(x±vt))$.

An equivalent convention would be to keep $(k(x - vt))$ as the only argument, but to let $v$ take positive or negative values.

Suppose that we keep $v$ as a positive constant (wave speed) AND keep $(k(x - vt))$ as the only argument, but allow $k$ to take positive or negative values. In that case, changing the sign of $k$ (from $k=k_1$ to $k=-k_1$, say) doesn't change the direction of travel, only the phase, since
$$\sin(-k_1(x-vt))=\sin(k_1(x-vt)+\pi).$$

In another answer – and possibly in your course – the argument of the sine is written as $(kx-\omega t)$. In that case, if $\omega$ is a positive constant, changing from a positive value of $k$ to a negative one, or vice versa, changes only the first term in the argument, and *does* change the direction of travel of the wave, since
$$\sin(-k_1 x-\omega t)=\sin(-(k_1 x+\omega t)=\sin(k_1 x+\omega t+\pi)$$

Sorry if this answer is more complicated than was expected.